# Remove item object multiples arrays when onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onclick

I have an array of an object with multiples arrays inside. I'm trying to remove the item when I click the button, but it's returning undefined

**Data Json**

```
[
  {
    "services": [
      {
        "id": "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
        "name": "PIX"
      },
      {
        "id": "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
        "name": "Income"
      }
    ],
    "accountTypes": [
      {
        "id": "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
        "name": "Digital Account"
      }
    ],
    "channels": [
      {
        "id": "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
        "name": "Chat"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**HandleDeleteItem**

```
const handleDeleteFilter = (itemId: string) => {
    const items = filters.flatMap((param) => {
      Object.entries(param).flatMap(([key, arr]) =>
        arr.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId)
      )
    })
    setFilters(items)
  }
```

**Function Button onClick**

```
onClick={() => handleDeleteFilter(filter.id)}
```

Comment: what is filter.id in the call of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first flatMap arrow function uses brackets (`=> { ... }`) but doesn't have a return statement. Try this instead:

```js
const handleDeleteFilter = (itemId: string) => {
    const items = filters.flatMap((param) => {
        // Added a return here
        return Object.entries(param).flatMap(([key, arr]) =>
            arr.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId)
        )
    })
    setFilters(items)
}
```

It isn't very clear what `filters` is (I assume your shown JSON), so I haven't checked whether your function is logically correct.